# Taking screenshots in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm trying to take screenshots of pages in a Rails 4 app. I've tried several ways but the cleanest seems to be by using capybara with poltergeist.

In my Gemfile I have the following:

```
gem 'capybara'
gem 'capybara-screenshot'
gem 'poltergeist'
```

and my rake task looks like this:

```
desc "Take a screenshot of top three articles"
task :screenshots => :environment do
  require 'capybara'
  require 'capybara/poltergeist'
  include Capybara::DSL
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
  Capybara.run_server = false

  articles = Article.order('score DESC').limit(3)

  articles.each do |article|
    visit(article.url)
    screenshot_and_save_page
  end
end
```

However, this is giving me errors like such:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL <someurl> from frame with URL http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=40#channel=fcf48aa3c&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.independent.co.uk. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Any clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this by adding the following:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :js_errors => false)
end
```